# Getting actual array of results using Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, activemodel

With a regular ActiveRecord/SQL setup in Rails, in console when I execute commands `*.where`, `*.all` etc., I get back the actual array of record items.  However, after switching to Mongoid, I instead get back a criteria.  How do I get the actual results?

This is what I get now...

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > App.all
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {},
  options:  {},
  class:    App,
  embedded: false>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you query a model in Mongoid, it returns a criteria object (as you've stated), it doesn't actually run the query until you request data from the criteria.

All you need to do is iterate over the results, using `each` or `map` or any of the array methods, like this:

```
App.all.each do |app|
  puts app.name
end
```

Alternatively, if you just want the array, you can just call `to_a` on the criteria:

```
App.all.to_a
```

Answer (score 19):

`App.all.entries` works as well.